# activerecord/mysql saves my latin1 data as utf8

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, encoding

In my database config I have:

```
  adapter: mysql
  database: xxx
  username: xxx
  password: xxx
  host: localhost
  encoding: 'latin1'
```

My table definition has: `DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

I put this at the top of my file:

```
# encoding: iso-8859-1
```

And yet still when I save my record and load it again the latin1 data has been mysteriously converted to utf8. Can someone suggest something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

What about the columns' encoding? You have to set the connection, the tables, the columns and the program encoding/charset to the same one to have your code work properly.

Comment: I tried changing my column definition to: varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 but I'm still having the same problem, it gets converted somewhere to utf8.

Comment: Check your program runtime configuration for character encoding. For example in PHP you can set your internal encoding to any valid character set in PHP maybe in ruby you can do something similar.

Comment: That's what the encoding line is for. I appreciate your taking the time to comment but if you're not familiar with these things there's not much chance your comments will be helpful.

Comment: The # encoding stand for only the parsing the file not for the runtime encoding and BTW latin1 is not iso-8859-1 but cp1252. What happens if you set your encoding in your database config yaml to BINARY? Maybe the bast solution is to change your database to utf-8.